# Is there listener for jenkins quietDown mode?

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins has **quietDown** mode which, according to 
[this article](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/216118748-How-to-Start-Stop-or-Restart-your-Instance-)
is:

> Put Jenkins in a Quiet mode, in preparation for a restart. In that mode Jenkins don’t start any build

Corresponding flag is enabled/disabled in `jenkins.model.Jenkins`
and for example can be accessible via http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/model/Jenkins.html#isQuietingDown-- method

My question is if there is any listener(perhaps `hudson.ExtensionPoint` - that is notified when jenkins goes into that mode) that could be implemented by my jenkins plugin?